# Flask- Not able to get request's body in any way

Tags: flask, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm learning how to make a API using AWS SAM and Flask. Here's my application:

```
import json
from flask import request
from flask_lambda import FlaskLambda

app = FlaskLambda(__name__)

@app.route('/submission', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def send_submissions():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return (
            json.dumps({
                'name': request.headers['Name']
            }),
            200,
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        return (
            json.dumps({
                'name': request.headers['Name'],
                'data': data
            }),
            200,
            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's the error I get by calling request.get_json() in line 20:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 20, in send_submissions
    data = request.get_json()
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py", line 611, in get_json
    data = self.get_data(cache=cache)
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py", line 423, in get_data
    rv = self.stream.read()
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 829, in readall
    data = self.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 810, in readinto
    b[:out_size] = data
TypeError: can assign only bytes, buffers, or iterables of ints in range(0, 256)
```

I get a similar error by replace this with request.get_data():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/var/task/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 20, in send_submissions
    data = request.get_data()
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/request.py", line 423, in get_data
    rv = self.stream.read()
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 829, in readall
    data = self.read(1024 * 64)
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 810, in readinto
    b[:out_size] = data
TypeError: can assign only bytes, buffers, or iterables of ints in range(0, 256)
```

And the output when I try request.form.to_dict() is just an empty dictionary. Here's my post request:

```
headers = {'Name': 'Foo', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(f"{base_url}/submission", data={"message": "Hello, World!"}, headers=headers)
```

Request's method and headers is working fine, and so is args, but I can't find any way to get the body data. I think this may have something to do with how FlaskLambda interacts with Flask, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's how you're sending the data. You should use `json` instead of `data` i.e.:

```
r = requests.post(f"{base_url}/submission", json={"message": "Hello, World!"}, headers=headers)
```

Comment: This still isn't working for me. I get the same error.